# Managing large AWS SQS payloads over S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I am working in a project Java 11/Spring boot project that I need to send and consume a SQS message that is over 256KB, that is the common limit for SQS. I can't change the modeling of the system in a way that the message will be lesser than 256KB.

I know AWS provides support for bigger payloads by using its SQS extended client library, that can be seen here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html#working-java-example-using-s3-for-large-sqs-messages-example

I copied and tested the example for sending the message, but still not sure about his behaviour on Spring Boot integration (@SqsListener) for consuming these kind of messages. The code worked successfuly, but I am not sure if the payload has been already deleted inside S3 bucket after consumption because I couldn't see the message been stored in there. In the example, deleting the message needs to be done manually, but I haven't coded it when I ran the code.

Do Spring Boot @SqsListener consumer already manages to delete the message, after consumption, and makes evething ready or I need to manage something yet?

Comment: I guess the client does not take care of deleting the messages from S3 - it deletes them from SQS, but not from S3. That is why there is a `BucketLifecycleConfiguration` in your linked post, that policy takes care of deleting messages in S3 after 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by debugging aws sdk code. I will put it here for anyone that needs this in the future.

I initially thought that the message was big enough, because I thought the encoding for char was taking 2 bytes per char, but by analizing the method, from aws, Util.getStringSizeInBytes, it was taking only 1 byte.

If you check the code from AmazonSQSExtendedClient.sendMessage, you will see that there is going to have this comaparison:

```
                if (this.clientConfiguration.isAlwaysThroughS3() || this.isLarge(sendMessageRequest)) {
                sendMessageRequest = this.storeMessageInS3(sendMessageRequest);
            }
```

Then I saw that this.isLarge and isAlwaysThroughS3 was both false, so it wasn't really using the S3 bucket at all. Then, for testing, I incresed the payload until isLarge change to true and then I could see the message in the S3 bucket.

One good tip also, is that when S3 is under use, the message sends just the S3 key on SQS.